# Unable to run cordova example project(phonegap)

Tags: cordova

In my eclipse adt i am unable to run the cordovaexample project (phonegap-2.9.1). When i click on RUN AS -> Android Application, the emulator loads and the message appears **unfortunately cordova example has stopped working**

Here is the snapshot[image]

Please explain how to run this project.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update to the latest cordova (3.4.1 currently) and retry. If you have an Android AVD running, you can move into the directory and run the example from the command line ("cordova emulate android") to see if that helps.

Comment: My cordova version is 3.4.1-0.1.0. Tried using command line, didn't help much.

Comment: It might be that the sample itself is not working on newer Android builds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303302/phonegap-cordova-example-waiting-for-home-android-process-acore-to-be-launch

Comment: You might actually have better luck looking at Christophe Coenraets' tutorial: http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/